# How to retrieve the text using protractor's getText API?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am using protractor for my test framework and I need to get the value by using the getText method and store it in another value. I have problem in extracting the value from getText method. I do understand that I need to resolve the promise but it didn't work for me.

I have the page object like this. (Emp.js)

```
this.getID = async()=>{
     await empID.getText();
```

}

and in the test.spec.js. This is how I have my test to retrieve the file.

```
var emp = new emp();    
let empID = await emp.getID();
//When I do console.log(empID) it returns undefined. not sure why ?
```

Comment: you can add `return` in your `getID` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
this.getID = async() => {
    return await empID.getText();
}
```